# Complexity of Bubble Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I have seen at lot of places, the complexity for bubble sort is  O(n<sup>2</sup>).

But how can that be so because the inner loop should always runs n-i times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < toSort.length -1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < toSort.length - 1 - i; j++) {
                if(toSort[j] > toSort[j+1]){
                    int swap = toSort[j+1];
                    toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
                    toSort[j] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

And what is the "average" value of `n-i` ? `n/2`

So it runs in `O(n*n/2)` which is considered as O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: But why don't we have that "/2"

Comment: @DeepakKumar because it has no meaning when you're dealing with scale. The big O notation deals with scale. Would you consider O(n) to be different from O(n-1) ? even though n != n-1 they have the same scale. Same applies to `n/2` and `n`.

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of time complexity - you are using big O notation so that means all cases of this function will be at least this time complexity.

As it approaches infinity this can be basically n^2 time complexity worst case scenario. Time complexity is not an exact art but more of a ballpark for what sort of speed you can expect for this class of algorithm and hence you are trying to be too exact.

For example the theoretical time complexity might very well be n^2 even though it should in theory be n*n-1 because of whatever unforeseen processing overhead might be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Since outer loop runs n times and for each iteration inner loop runs (n-i) times , the total number of operations can be calculated as 
n*(n-i) = O(n2).

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n^2),because length * length.